# What happens if we are trying to check if a blob exists in a container but that container doesn't exist?

Tags: azure, blob

I'm trying to do `blobContainerClient.IfBlobExistsAsync()` and I want to know what happens if the blobContainerClient doesn't exist, thanks!

Comment: If you have the code ready, you could just change the container name to a non-existing one to see what happens.

Comment: Which SDK are you using? Plus, please add the relevant code snippet.

Comment: If you are using C#, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61128794/how-do-you-check-that-a-container-exists-in-azure-blob-storage-v12)

Comment: C# , refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.exists?view=azure-dotnet)

and if using Python, refer [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_authentication.py#L50)